# Get metadata from InputStream by using Dropbox sdk for Objective-C

Tags: objective-c, macos, dropbox-api, xcode4.6

I wanna get the metadata from inputStream by using dropbox sdk when I load a file from dropbox space.

But I don't have any information of inputStream.

Is there anyone who can resolve this issue or share any ideas?

Please let me know. Many thanks.

Comment: Which SDK are you using? (Core or Sync?) What method are you calling to get the inputStream?

Comment: I have solved the issue by using the method "loadStreamableURLForFile" form core api.

Thanks.